# bind event handlers to dynamically created elements via recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, recursion, dynamically-generated

I want to create an editable table, such that if all the cells of the last row have content, a new row is added automatically. For the cells in the new row, the same event handler should be binded.
Here is my code, what is wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").keyup(function(){keyupper($(this))});
});




function keyupper(cell){

// mark all changed cells by yellow
$(cell).css("background-color","rgb(255,255,150)");

 /* if all cells in last row are filled, add new row
    */
$("tbody tr:last-child").each(function (){

        //$this is the last row
    var td0 = $(this).children().eq(0).text();
    var td1 = $(this).children().eq(1).text();
    var td2 = $(this).children().eq(2).text();
    var td3 = $(this).children().eq(3).text();
    var td4 = $(this).children().eq(4).text();


        //if all fields are filled

    if(td0!="" && td1!="" && td2!="" && td3!="" && td4!=""){
        //parent of this is tbody
        $(this).parent().append("<tr><td contenteditable></td>"
            +"<td contenteditable></td>"
            +"<td contenteditable></td>"
            +"<td contenteditable></td>"
            +"<td contenteditable></td></tr>");
        $(addedcells) = $(this).parent().children().last().children();
        /// list of the cells added in the last row
        /// binding the event handler function via recursion
        $(addedcells).eq(0).bind("keyup",function(){
            keyupper($(addedcells).eq(0));});
        $(addedcells).eq(1).bind("keyup",function(){
            keyupper($(addedcells).eq(1));});
        $(addedcells).eq(2).bind("keyup",function(){
            keyupper($(addedcells).eq(2));});
        $(addedcells).eq(3).bind("keyup",function(){
            keyupper($(addedcells).eq(3));});
        $(addedcells).eq(4).bind("keyup",function(){
            keyupper($(addedcells).eq(4));});

    }

});
}
```

Comment: What works and what does not work??

Comment: The first part of the function (adding new row) works, but the last part (binding the same function for an event of the added cells) does not work.

Comment: Ok where is your html to know which parent and which children you have

Comment: Oh , stupid syntax error.
Instead of $(addedcells) I should use $addedcells everywhere.
I am sorry.
Now everything works perfectly. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried jQuery on() function and it solves the problem. 
It allows to assign event handlers for elements not created yet.

for example

```
$("tbody").on("keyup","td",function(){
    keyupper($(this))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the following statement at the end of "keyupper" function?

```
$("td").keyup(function(){keyupper($(this))});
```

Comment: This makes a browser hanging when typing...
I guess a lot of event handlers are being attached each time

Comment: Please post your html first.